# do we call the 2 strips of a masquerade mask "laces"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

When we talk a bout mask, it could be "a medical face mask"
[image]

And "a medical face mask" has 2 ear loops, for example, "**put the ear loops around your ears**"

or it could be "a masquerade mask"

[image]

We weed to tie a bow to put on a masquerade mask.

**do we call the 2 strips of a masquerade mask "laces"**?

**Note**: But I feel that laces are strings that go through holes in clothing before being tied.

So, I am not sure "lace" is the right word because there is no holes needed when tying the 2 strips of a masquerade mask.

Comment: They could be called strings by analogy with *apron strings*.

Comment: Laces, yes, or ties.

Comment: I agree that _laces_ isn't the right word. You could call them _ribbons_, since that is what they appear to be made of.

Comment: Or: you have to tie the ties. Laces are for shoes.